# The C preprocessor operator ##

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am reading another post but I can't get my program to work. I need to use two constants defined with the C preprocessor in a new constant. It is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM 5000 
#define ARCHIVOMATRIZ "matrizDiagonalDominante.txt"
#define ARCHIVODESTINO DIM ##_## ARCHIVOMATRIZ
int main(){

    printf("Iniciando ejecucion del programa.\n");


    printf("%s\n", ARCHIVODESTINO);
    printf("Listo\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But when I want to show my new constant, it doesn't work. 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you expect as output?  You can't start an identifier with a number; you normally use a macro argument with the `##` operator.

Comment: Hi. I am trying to make a string that will be the name of a file text. It s will have two parts..A number  taken of DIM (5000,6000,7000, etc ) and the name of the file taken of ARCHIVOMATRIZ. I want make the name of the file like : 5000matrizDiagonalDominante.txt, 6000MatrizDiagonalDominante, etc.

Comment: Please add that information to the question, where you can format it.  I also recommend removing the commented out code from your question; it serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260327/the-c-preprocessor-operator?noredirect=1#comment79502547_46260327):

> I am trying to make a string that will be the name of a file text. It s will have two parts: A number taken of `DIM` (5000, 6000, 7000, etc) and the name of the file taken of `ARCHIVOMATRIZ`. I want make the name of the file like : `5000matrizDiagonalDominante.txt`, `6000MatrizDiagonalDominante.txt`, etc.

The correct operator to be using is the 'stringizing' operator, `#`, rather than the token concatenation operator `##`.

I think this does what you want:

```
#define DIM 5000 
#define ARCHIVOMATRIZ "matrizDiagonalDominante.txt"
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define NAME_FROM_MACROS(x, y)   STRINGIZE(x) y
#define ARCHIVODESTINO NAME_FROM_MACROS(DIM, ARCHIVOMATRIZ)
```

It relies on 'string concatenation'.  When two string literals are adjacent to each other with only (optional) white space separating them, the compiler combines them into a single string literal.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 5000 
#define ARCHIVOMATRIZ "matrizDiagonalDominante.txt"
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define NAME_FROM_MACROS(x, y)   STRINGIZE(x) y
#define ARCHIVODESTINO NAME_FROM_MACROS(DIM, ARCHIVOMATRIZ)

int main(void)
{
    printf("Archivo destino: %s\n", ARCHIVODESTINO);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Archivo destino: 5000matrizDiagonalDominante.txt
```

If you want an underscore between the parts of the name, then use:

```
#define NAME_FROM_MACROS(x, y)   STRINGIZE(x) "_" y
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Lefftler for your aswer.